# change name=type to id=type

Tags: jquery, input, show-hide

i am currently using this code to make input boxes appear and disappear depending on what my user has selected

```
<label class="title">Is the Primary Contact a Director of the corporation?</label>
<input type="radio"{if freeform:mp_data:type=="Yes"} checked="checked"{/if} name="type" id="primary_contact_director_1" value="Yes"> Yes</input><br>
<input type="radio"{if freeform:mp_data:type=="No"} checked="checked"{/if} name="type" id="primary_contact_director_2" value="No"> No</input><br><br>
<div id="Yes_box">

</div>
<div id="No_box">
<label class="title">Director's First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_first_name" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_first_name}">

<label class="title">Director's Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_last_name" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_last_name}">

<label class="title">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_address" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_address}">

<label class="title">City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_city" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_city}">

<label class="title">State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_state" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_state}">

<label class="title">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="director_zip_code" class="form" value="{freeform:mp_data:director_zip_code}">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var myRadio = $('input[name=type]');
var checkedValue = myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
if(checkedValue=='No'){
    $('#No_box').show();
}else{
    $('#No_box').hide();
}
$('#Yes_box_two').hide();

});
</script>
```

i however need the name field in order to display the results so i would like to change the input[name=type] to call on the id instead of the name

Comment: ...and your question is...?

Comment: question could use somemore clarity.

Comment: i just need to figure out how to accomplish the show/hide by calling the id and not the name.

Answer (score 0):

So change

```
var myRadio = $('input[name=type]');
```

to

```
var myRadio = $('input[id=type]');
```

or

```
var myRadio = $('input#type');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused, your following line:

```
var myRadio = $('input[name=type]');
```

should really be like this so to make sense:

```
var myRadio = $('input[type=radio]');
```

Comment: the way i had it with $('input[name=type]'); was working fine, i tried to switch it to your example and it actually broke.